# Can I put a linode instance behind our corporate firewall

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, firewall

I've built a little web application to collect internal survey data on a linode instance that I'd like to use in my company.

My company already has windows servers set up that run intranet sites under the following address pattern `servername.companyname.com`. These sites are visible to anyone logged into our network, but are invisible if you try to access them externally.

What I'm trying to figure out is:

1. Can I make it so that my service is only visible within our network
2. How do I give the service a name that I want
3. What potential risks are there to this type of set-up for a short-term, non critical project
4. How do I phrase this question to IT without sounding like an idiot

Thanks,

-JWW

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you are not the system or network admin (your point 4 is "How do I make this request to IT without sounding like an idiot?" -- the answer is "You schedule an appointment with someone responsible for your environment, discuss your needs with them, and work with them to implement a solution." -- that's why you have an IT department :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Configure a VPN on it so that it appears as an internal server and configure firewall rules to only allow traffic coming over the VPN tunnel to the server.
2. DNS
3. The risks are that you don't seem to be familiar with how to set this up, so there's always the chance that you break it or don't properly secure it and then you effectively have an internet-facing server with access to your internal network.
4. If you don't know what you're asking for, just explain your requirements.